# Centered divs in small size, but in one row on larger sizes in foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am trying to create two divs using foundation.

I used this code:

```
<div id=”containerLeftWrap” class=”small-4 small-centered medium-offset-2 medium-2 medium-uncentered columns” >
    …content…
</div>

<div id="containerRight" class="medium-7 columns">
      <div id="aboutArea">
      …content…
      </div>
</div>
```

In small size it looks fine

[image]

but in the medium and large size it looks like this
[image]

instead of like this
[image]

I've tried to add:

```
style=”display:inline-block; vertical-align:top”
```

But then the first div (the smaller one) was stuck to the left side, in all sizes, like this:
[image]

Does someone have an idea how to solve this?

Thank you!!!!

**Update:**

I have this css:

```
#containerLeftWrap {
  background-color: #262626;
height: 256px;
min-width: 245px;
    padding-top: 28px;
border-radius: 7px;
margin-top: 60px;
}
#aboutArea {
width: 90%;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #262626; 
border-radius: 7px;
padding-bottom: 15px;  
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if you have styles set for "containerLeftWrap" and "containerRight" that's causing the issue?

Comment: See updated question please